# Set opacity 30% for duration of 0.5s

Tags: javascript, jquery

My task is to set thumbnail images to opacity 30% for duration of 0.5s upon hoverover. I am very new to this and not sure if i am doing this right. Can anyone advise to my code in js file?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  // Add the hover handler to the link
  $("#imageCS").hover(
    function(){ // When mouse pointer is above the link
      // Make the image inside link to be transparent
      $(this).find("images/boxImage1").animate(
        {opacity:"0.3"},
        {duration:500}
      );
    },
    function(){ // When mouse pointer move out of the link
      // Return image to its previous state
      $(this).find("images/boxImage1").animate(
        {opacity:"1"},
        {duration:300}
  
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add the hover handler to the link
  $("#imageCS").hover(
    function(){ // When mouse pointer is above the link
      // Make the image inside link to be transparent
      $(this).find("images/boxImage2").animate(
        {opacity:"0.3"},
        {duration:500}
      );
    },
    function(){ // When mouse pointer move out of the link
      // Return image to its previous state
      $(this).find("images/boxImage1").animate(
        {opacity:"1"},
        {duration:300}

$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add the hover handler to the link
  $("#imageCS").hover(
    function(){ // When mouse pointer is above the link
      // Make the image inside link to be transparent
      $(this).find("images/boxImage1").animate(
        {opacity:"0.3"},
        {duration:500}
      );
    },
    function(){ // When mouse pointer move out of the link
      // Return image to its previous state
      $(this).find("images/boxImage3").animate(
        {opacity:"1"},
        {duration:300}
</html>
</body>
</script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <title>TMA</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="socialmediafloat">
    <img src="images/facebook.png" id="facebook_icon" class="media_icons"/>
        <img src="images/twitter.png" id="twitter_icon" class="media_icons"/>
        <img src="images/youtube.png" id="youtube_icon" class="media_icons"/>
        <img src="images/pinterest.png" id="pinterest_icon" class="media_icons"/>
</div>
<div id="myheader">
 <div id="header" class="container">
  <div id="logo">
   <h1><a href="http://www.unisim.edu.sg/Pages/UniSIM.aspx"><img src="images/UniSIM.JPG"/></a></h1>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="highlights" class="container">
  <div class="title">
   <h1>Discover The UniSIM Advantage</h1>
   <span class="byline">Are you ready to open your mind to more possibilities, give yourself the opportunities that you've always wanted, and quench your thirst for knowledge? No matter what it is, whether to give yourself a second chance in your career or to provide for a better life for yourself and your loved ones, further education with UniSIM will get you there.</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
 <div id="myCols" class="container">
  <div class="col1">
            <img src="images/boxImage1.jpg" class="imageCS"/>
   <p>Whatever your goals, background or life stage, we believe in you, and we will equip you with the real-world knowledge and practice-oriented skills to excel, both in life and in your chosen career.</p>
   <button id="col1btn" class="button">Discover</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
            <img src="images/boxImage2.png" class="imageCS"/>
   <p>With a range of more than 50 degree programmes in various disciplines, we focus on equipping our students with a competitive advantage in their industries. Explore the programmes we offer from our five schools and embark on your learning journey now.</p>
   <button id="col2btn" class="button">Programmes</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col3">
            <img src="images/boxImage3.jpg" class="imageCS"/>
   <p>SIM University (UniSIM) offers government-funded, full-time direct honours programme for school leavers. A full-time degree can normally be completed in 4 years although the maximum period of candidature is 6 years.</p>
   <button id="col3btn" class="button">Education</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="details">
 <div class="container">
        <p>BSc Multimedia Technology and Design</p>
        <table id="MTDSchedule">
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Credit Units</th> 
            <th>Time Table</th>  
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>ICT271</td>
            <td>Introductory Programming Techniques in C++</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Thursday/Week 1/Term 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>MTD105e</td>
            <td>Digital Photography Techniques</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Friday / Week 2 / Term 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>MTD111e</td>
            <td>Creative Design Fundamentals</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Wednesday / Week 1 / Term 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>MTD113e</td>
            <td>History of Media</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Wednesday / Week 1 / Term 2</td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>MTD201e</td>
            <td>Fundamentals of Graphics Design</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Tuesday / Week 1 / Term 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>MTD203e</td>
            <td>Advanced Graphics Design</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Tuesday / Week 2 / Term 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>MTD205e</td>
            <td>Audio Technology</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Wednesday / Week 1 / Term 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>MTD207e</td>
            <td>Video Technology</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Wednesday / Week 1 / Term 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>MTD215</td>
            <td>Application of C++ in Multimedia</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Wednesday / Week 1 / Term 2</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <button class="button">Reset</button>
    </div> 
</div>
<div id="footer" class="container">
    <p>&copy; All rights reserved. | SIM University</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us your code then?

Comment: maybe you could minimise it so that only the relevant code is seen and we can readily test it.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but I think you'll want something like this:

```
$(".imageCS").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 0.3
  }, 500 );
});

$(".imageCS").mouseout(function(){
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 300 );
});
```

Since `imageCS` is a class, you want to have your JQuery selector set as `.imageCS` and not `#imageCS` (which would be used for a div id as opposed to a class).  Additionally, since it is a class this means you can access all of the images with that class at once rather than having to do the mouseover events for each one separately.  And you don't have to find the image url, just the image tag itself, so just `this` without doing the `.find` is fine.

Also, if you have access to the CSS I would actually do these hover events there using CSS3 transitions (as opposed to the JQuery/JS solution proposed above).  It would be simpler and cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Use the effect on the `mouseenter` event and then restore `opacity` to 1 with `setTimeout`.

Example:

```js
$('#so').mouseenter(function() {
  $('#so').animate({opacity: 0.3});
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#so').animate({opacity: 1})
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- sample image -->
<div id="so-img-div">
  <img id="so" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" style="border:1px solid black">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this effect with CSS?

```js
  $imgWrapper = $('.image--wrapper');

 $imgWrapper.hover(
    //this function will run when you hover your image
   function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
   }, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
   }
 );
```

```css
img {
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.active img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image--wrapper">
  <img src= "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" />
</div>
```